# How to fetch current location when users move in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation

am new to ios developing am developing a app using mapview in swift.The app is connected between driver and passenger.if the driver starts drive,every 15 seconds drivers current location should be update.how to do that??
what i have tried:
1)I turn on my capabilities from target of the project 
2)selected location updates and background fetch
3)I have displayed and fetched current location

Comment: can show ur tried code

Comment: It is very important not to think of the location as something you get every so often. But more like the system will tell you when the location has changed. Thus if I sit at my desk the hole day there are no location updates at that moment. Yet when I go home the location will change and your app can get informed about these changes.

Comment: I have edited my question.please help me to that process....@rckoenes

Comment: i have not tried.am searching for the hint....@Anbu.Karthik